# Iterating over all elements of column and apply function to values

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have the following dataframe:

```
data = {'id':[1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4,], 'names':['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'd', 'c', 'a']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I define a function

```
def myfunc(x,y):
   return list(set(x+y))
```

I want to iterate over all pair id's and apply the function to their 'names' values, e.g., for id 1 and id 2, it would be list_1 = ['a'], list_2 = ['b', 'a', 'c'], and the result would be myfunc(list_1, list_2).

The code does not have to do id=[1,2] and [2,1], as it would be the same (sort of like distance).

I have tried with groupby on 'id', but I haven't found a way to iterate one id over all the rest.

The expected output should be

```
  id_1 id_2 res
  1     2   ['a', 'b', 'c']
  1     3   ['a', 'e']
  2     3   ['a', 'b', 'c', 'e']
```

and so on. Thanks!

Comment: sorry, why is group 4 not involved?

Comment: Sorry @juanpa.arrivillaga! I just didn't add them in the example output. They are involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished entirely through the use of data manipulation methods on DataFrames.

Assuming the input DataFrame:

```
   id names
0   1     a
1   2     b
2   2     a
3   2     c
4   3     e
5   3     a
6   4     b
7   4     d
8   4     c
9   4     a
```

Consider the following steps:

---

##### 1) Group the data by `id` (as you suggested), combining the names of each group to a single `list`.

After using `.groupby()`, you can use the [`.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) method to apply a function to every group (each treated like a sub-DataFrame).

```py
# Start by grouping DataFrame by the id field.
id_groups = df.groupby('id')

# Extract the names column from each group as lists.
id_names = id_groups.apply(lambda x: list(x['names']))

# Convert it to a DataFrame by unsetting the 'id' field as the index.
lists_df = id_names.reset_index()

# Reset the names of the columns
lists_df.columns = ["id", "values"]

print(lists_df)
```

```
   id        values
0   1           [a]
1   2     [b, a, c]
2   3        [e, a]
3   4  [b, d, c, a]
```

---

##### 2) Produce all the possible `id` combinations by "cross-joining".

The [`.merge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) method allows one to perform SQL joins. In this case it can be used to "cross-join" the DataFrame onto itself to produce all the `id` combinations.

```py
# "Cross-join" the DataFrame, producing all the possible id combinations.
cross_df = lists_df.merge(lists_df, how='cross', suffixes = ['_1', '_2'])
```

```
    id_1      values_1  id_2      values_2
0      1           [a]     1           [a]
1      1           [a]     2     [b, a, c]
2      1           [a]     3        [e, a]
3      1           [a]     4  [b, d, c, a]
4      2     [b, a, c]     1           [a]
5      2     [b, a, c]     2     [b, a, c]
6      2     [b, a, c]     3        [e, a]
7      2     [b, a, c]     4  [b, d, c, a]
8      3        [e, a]     1           [a]
9      3        [e, a]     2     [b, a, c]
10     3        [e, a]     3        [e, a]
11     3        [e, a]     4  [b, d, c, a]
12     4  [b, d, c, a]     1           [a]
13     4  [b, d, c, a]     2     [b, a, c]
14     4  [b, d, c, a]     3        [e, a]
15     4  [b, d, c, a]     4  [b, d, c, a]
```

---

##### 3) Trim down the `id` combinations to remove all the duplicates.

These combinations can then be trimmed to remove matching pairs (e.g. `(1, 1)`), as well as equivalent pairs (e.g. `(1, 2)` and `(2, 1)`). To do the latter brief sort the id pairs of each the DataFrame, then remove the duplicates using the [`.drop_duplicates()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) method.

```py
# Keep only the rows with unmatching id pairs.
cross_df = cross_df[cross_df["id_1"] != cross_df["id_2"]]

# Have every pair (id_1, id_2) in sorted order, with id_1 < id_2
cross_df[["id_1", "id_2"]] = cross_df[["id_1", "id_2"]].apply(lambda x : x.sort_values(ignore_index=True), 
                                                              axis = 'columns')
# Drop the resulting duplicate (id_1, id_2) rows.
cross_df = cross_df.drop_duplicates(["id_1", "id_2"], ignore_index = True)

print(cross_df)
```

```
   id_1   values_1  id_2      values_2
0     1        [a]     2     [b, a, c]
1     1        [a]     3        [e, a]
2     1        [a]     4  [b, d, c, a]
3     2  [b, a, c]     3        [e, a]
4     2  [b, a, c]     4  [b, d, c, a]
5     3     [e, a]     4  [b, d, c, a]
```

---

##### 4) Apply `myfunct()` to each pair.

By appropriately setting the `axis` argument, the `.apply()` function can be used to apply a function (in this case, `myfunc()`) to each row of the DataFrame.

```py
# For each row of pairs apply the function to their corresponding values (sorting the result).
cross_df["res"] = cross_df.apply(lambda r: sorted(myfunc(r["values_1"], r["values_2"])), 
                                 axis = "columns")

print(cross_df)
```

```
   id_1   values_1  id_2      values_2              res
0     1        [a]     2     [b, a, c]        [a, b, c]
1     1        [a]     3        [e, a]           [a, e]
2     1        [a]     4  [b, d, c, a]     [a, b, c, d]
3     2  [b, a, c]     3        [e, a]     [a, b, c, e]
4     2  [b, a, c]     4  [b, d, c, a]     [a, b, c, d]
5     3     [e, a]     4  [b, d, c, a]  [a, b, c, d, e]
```

---

##### 5) Extract only the columns you want to output

At this point all the main work is done. From here simply extract only the columns you are interested in.

```py
# Getting the relevant columns:
pairs_df = cross_df[["id_1", "id_2", "res"]]

print(pairs_df)
```

Final output:

```
   id_1  id_2              res
0     1     2        [a, b, c]
1     1     3           [a, e]
2     1     4     [a, b, c, d]
3     2     3     [a, b, c, e]
4     2     4     [a, b, c, d]
5     3     4  [a, b, c, d, e]
```

---

#### Full code:

```py
def myfunc(x,y):
    return list(set(x+y))


# --- Step 1: Grouping the data together by the id field. 

id_groups = df.groupby('id')

id_names = id_groups.apply(lambda x: list(x['names']))

lists_df = id_names.reset_index()

lists_df.columns = ["id", "values"]


# --- Step 2: Producing all the combinations of id pairs.

cross_df = lists_df.merge(lists_df, how='cross', suffixes = ['_1', '_2'])


# --- Step 3: Removing matching/duplicate combinations

cross_df = cross_df[cross_df["id_1"] != cross_df["id_2"]]

cross_df[["id_1", "id_2"]] = cross_df[["id_1", "id_2"]].apply(lambda x : x.sort_values(ignore_index=True), 
                                                              axis = 'columns')

cross_df = cross_df.drop_duplicates(["id_1", "id_2"], ignore_index = True)


# --- Step 4: Applying each pair to the function.

cross_df["res"] = cross_df.apply(lambda r: sorted(myfunc(r["values_1"], r["values_2"])), 
                                 axis = "columns")


# --- Step 5: Gathering together the relevant rows.

pairs_df = cross_df[["id_1", "id_2", "res"]]
```

Comment: Thanks @user21283023 ! This is what I needed it! I changed some of the apply methods as my array grows too much (~3000 unique users), but it works! Thanks!

Comment: And thanks for all the clear explanations! Quite useful!